# How to define a variable in php with some html text?

Tags: php, html, variables

i'm trying to create a table with some button, a, glyphicon, span etc... but it is dynamic and goes inside php text. The table and the dynamic variables are showed but when I add  everythings die. This is my code:

```
$output .= '<tr> <td>
   <a href="productos.php?edit=<?=$product['id'];?>" class="btn btn-xs btn-default border"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a>
   <a href="productos.php?delete=<?=$product['id'];?>" class="btn btn-xs btn-default border"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a>
 </td> <td>'.$product["Title"].'</td>
<td>'.money($product["Price"]).'</td>
<td>'.$category.'</td>
<td>'.$row1["mobile"].'</td></tr> ';' }
```

Comment: replace 
<?= with '. 
;?> with .'
you are already in php context, so these two are not needed.

Comment: Thanks men now it works!